# IronRuby dead slow under debug

Tags: c#, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I've just integrated SassAndCoffee into a project. It works great, with the exception of debugging. A single request to a .scss resource returns in **50ms**. Hit F5 and refresh, and the exact same request takes **1300ms**. (I'm measuring second request oneward of course - first request takes longer for other reasons).

Using dotTrace, the culprit appears to be IronRuby:

[image: iron ruby dotTrace]

Is this a known issue? Is there some fix for this?